# dynamic casting to unknown derived class

Tags: dynamic, casting, abstract

What is the  best way to be able to cast a dynamic object to an unknown object type.

```
public abstract class VehicleBase{ }
```

public abstract class Car : VehicleBase { }

public abstract class Truck : VehicleBase { }

public abstract class Sedan : Car{ }

I need way to be able to cast a dynamic object that could be object Car, Truck or Sedan?  Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Why* do you need to be able to cast? What are you trying to achieve? What language are you using? (I suspect it's C#, but you should specify.)

Comment: might we ask why? There could be a better way.

Comment: Also. in my case, class Car, Truck, and Sedan will not be located within the same assembly as class VehicleBase if that helps, or changes the desired solution.

Comment: I am using C# .net 4.0

Comment: To Bathsheba: As to why I need to do this I will need to explain the exact case to clear it up. I have a base Testcase class that I want to derive a more specific type of test on top of, and then there are cases when I want too and more detailed testcase on top of that case.

Comment: Now when I am calling this test, I am trying to use a very generic TestManager object that has no idea what type of test that is being asked to call, but we know that they all are based on the TestBase class.

Comment: Also i am using the  Activator.CreateInstance to try to cast the test object from a parsed string. but I don't know that my specific object type I am casting into, I only know what my base class is.  IF this is even possible.